# Complexity of lookups in B-Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

How can I compute the complexity of look-ups in a B-tree where the branching factor is **100**? Do I even need the branching factor? I think this question might just be misleading me.

On Google, it says that the big-o lookuptime for a B-tree is `O(log(n))`. This is why I'm really confused as to why this could depend on branching factor? Does that mean that the answer is `O(log_100(n))`?

Thanks

Comment: log on every base is just log on base 2 times a factor according to logarithm rules.

Comment: this might answer you https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/59453/why-is-b-tree-search-olog-n/60041

Comment: The base of the logarithm is not significant in big O: O(log2(n)) = O(log10(n)) = O(log100(n))

Answer (score 0):

A lookup in such a data structure would require:-

```
O(log(100) * log(number of elements)/log(2))
```

Depth of the tree would be `log(number of elements)/log(100)` where log is base2.

Searching for which child to descent to will require `log(100)` operations using Binary Search.